# How to display NULL value as unchecked state in a TDBCheckBox descendant?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Having a nullable dataset field of a boolean type, how to display its `NULL` value as an unchecked state in a `TDBCheckBox` control descendant linked to this field. By default, `TDBCheckBox` displays the `NULL` value of the field as a grayed check box:

[image]

but I need it to be displayed as an unchecked state in my `TDBCheckBox` control descendant:

[image]

Modifying the original `TDBCheckBox` source code is not an option for me, nor I cannot override the `TDBCheckBox.GetFieldState` because it's a private method.

So, how can I display the `NULL` value as an unchecked state in my `TDBCheckBox` descendant ?

Comment: sorry for my English :-)

Comment: Having only Delphi 2009 by hand right now... There's not much code for this control, so you may consider creating a `TCustomCheckBox` control descendant. Or you can override the `TDBCheckBox`'s constructor providing your own handlers for the `FDataLink`'s `OnDataChange` and `OnUpdateData` events (turning off the `AllowGrayed` property). Or you can `COALESCE(Field, False)` your field data when fetching (if that's an option). Or you can make a calculated field for the dataset. Or maybe the dataset provider can do this cast globally for you...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I overrided the TDBCheckBox's constructor  for the FDataLink's OnDataChange and OnUpdateData  events but it doesn't work ((. I have a lot of datasets, so I can't add a calculated field.

Comment: Err, taking back my idea with providing event handlers for the `FDataLink`, it's a private field only, at least in D2009 (cannot say if that changed, nor even what version do you have). It's nearly closed control there.

Comment: Maybe I can use WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT?

Comment: At painting stage, the field state is being read when the `csPaintCopy` state is included in the control's state (when a copy of the control is being painted), so no. But I'm talking about the code I'm looking at, which version of Delphi do you use ? Could you [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28119398/edit) and include a version tag there, please ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the question. I used Delphi 6 (2000 something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help!

I implemented it following way:

```
  type
  TDBCheckBoxHack = class(TDBCheckBox)
    FDataLink: TFieldDataLink;
    procedure DataChange(Sender: TObject); virtual;
    function GetFieldState: TCheckBoxState; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
```

In constructor I used message CM_GETDATALINK for retrieve DataLink to my component

```
  constructor TDBCheckBoxHack.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  var
    AMessage: TMessage;
  begin
    inherited;
    FillChar(AMessage, 0, sizeof(AMessage));
    AMessage.Msg := CM_GETDATALINK;
    Dispatch(AMessage);
    FDataLink := TFieldDataLink(Pointer(AMessage.Result));
    FDataLink.OnDataChange := DataChange;
  end;
```

and GetFieldState implementation:

```
  function TFsDBCheckBox.GetFieldState: TCheckBoxState;
  var
    Text: string;
  begin
    if FDatalink.Field <> nil then
      if FDataLink.Field.IsNull then
        Result := cbUnchecked
      else if FDataLink.Field.DataType = ftBoolean then
        if FDataLink.Field.AsBoolean then
          Result := cbChecked
        else
          Result := cbUnchecked
      else
      begin
        Result := cbGrayed;
        Text := FDataLink.Field.Text;
        if ValueMatch(ValueChecked, Text) then Result := cbChecked else
          if ValueMatch(ValueUnchecked, Text) then Result := cbUnchecked;
      end
   else
     Result := cbUnchecked;
 end;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your project is closed source I suggest taking a copy of `DBCtrls`, change that one line where it says `Result := cbGrayed` and add that explicitly to your project. The change will be in your entire application but did not change the original code.

However there is another way - actually a hack so *be careful* and I suggest putting a compiler directive preventing this to be compiled in a different Delphi version to require looking at that code again and making sure it works.

Here is the code that works in Delphi XE - it might look different in Delphi 6 but you will get the idea.

```
type
  TDBCheckBoxHack = class(TCustomCheckBox)
  private
    FDataLink: TFieldDataLink;
    FValueCheck: string;
    FValueUncheck: string;
    procedure DataChange(Sender: TObject);
    function GetFieldState: TCheckBoxState;
    function ValueMatch(const ValueList, Value: string): Boolean;
  end;
```

I leave the implementation of these methods out because they are just a copy from the original copyrighted code. You have to change one or two lines in the `GetFieldState` method.

The trick is to create the same memory layout as the original TDBCheckBox so you can access the private fields - that is why this code should be used with care!

Then you assign the fixed `DataChange` method to the datalink:

```
TDBCheckBoxHack(DBCheckBox1).FDataLink.OnDataChange := 
  TDBCheckBoxHack(DBCheckBox1).DataChange;
```

To make this easier to use you can use another trick of inheriting from the original `TDBCheckBox` and call your class exactly the same. You can then put this into some unit and add this *after* the `DBCtrls` in your uses. That causes calling your constructor for every `TDBCheckBox` you placed on your form without the need to use your own and register it to the IDE:

```
type
  TDBCheckBox = class(DBCtrls.TDBCheckBox)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TDBCheckBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  TDBCheckBoxHack(Self).FDataLink.OnDataChange := TDBCheckBoxHack(Self).DataChange;
end;
```

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the excellent answer - especially the last part - makes it simple to add  to existing units (and simple to remove if it blows up!)